# Is startup.el really used?

Tags: emacs, config

I'm on windows, and according to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html) `startup.el` is used at the startup of emacs. But when I set code in this file (`C:\Users\frountch\Progs\emacs24\share\emacs\24.3.50\lisp\startup.el` in my case, after deleting the `.elc` file), it is not executed.

For instance I change the `defun normal-top-level` from:

```
(defun normal-top-level ()
  "Emacs calls this function when it first starts up.
It sets `command-line-processed', processes the command-line,
reads the initialization files, etc.
It is the default value of the variable `top-level'."

  (if command-line-processed
      (message "Back to top level.")
```

to

```
(devar myload (load-path))
(devar myload2 nil)
(defun normal-top-level ()
  "fuuuuuuu"
  (setq myload2 (load-path))
  (if command-line-processed
      (message "Back to top level.")
```

After that, `myload` and `myload2` are not defined.

Worse, if I delete `startup.el` and `startup.elc`, emacs can still be launched!

Is `startup.el` really used? How can I check that?

If I define

```
(defun normal-top-level ()
"fuuuuu"
  (message "fuuu"
  )
  )
```

in `startup.el` (`startup.elc` still deleted), when I `C-h f`, the help windows still shows

> normal-top-level is a compiled Lisp function in `startup.el'.
>
> (normal-top-level)
>
> Emacs calls this function when it first starts up. It sets
>   `command-line-processed', processes the command-line, reads the
>   initialization files, etc. It is the default value of the variable`
>   top-level'.

But when I click on `'startup.el'.` it opens my defun (with fuuu)!?

Is this a Win$ specific problem? is the startup really inside the binary?

version is 24.3.50.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startup.el` isn't used in a standard Emacs binary.  Note that [Startup Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html) doesn't suggest this.  It doesn't say that the source library `startup.el` is actually loaded during startup.  It merely states that a function defined in `startup.el` is called at startup.

`startup.el` is one of the essential core libraries that are “dumped” into the Emacs binary during compilation, to decrease startup time and increase performance.  Hence, the compiled Emacs binary does not load the source library `startup.el`, but instead reads its compiled byte code from the data section of the Emacs binary.

Yet, the *code in `startup.el`* is part of an Emacs binary, and evaluated at startup.  While you can't check this directly by modifying `startup.el` in a precompiled Emacs distribution, you can easily verify this by reading the source code of Emacs, or by building Emacs from source with a patched `startup.el`.

This is not specific to Windows.  In this regard, Emacs behaves the same on all supported operating systems.

Please note that `startup.el` is not intended to be modified by the user.  Use `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to configure and customize your Emacs.

Comment: Thanks, I am reassured. But what you are saying is that there is no way to change `normal-top-level` or print `load-path` before `normal-top-level-add-to-load-path` do anything except by "duping"/rebuilding Emacs? What a shame...

Comment: @frountch Why do you want to change `normal-top-level`? What can you do in that function that you can't do in your `init.el` as well?